# when i used inputstream reader i can't exit from the while loop after reading the data from the buffered reader

Tags: java, android, sockets, bufferedreader

```
 Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String number;
                    list.clear();
                      while ((number=br.readLine())!=null){
                       list.add(number);

                        }
```

while i trying to read the data from the buffered reader,i got the data.But i can't exit from the while loop if number equals null.

Comment: Your code is working as designed. It will exit that loop at end of stream. Unclear what you're expecting, or asking.

Comment: while i trying to read the data from the buffered reader,i got the data.But i can't exit from the while loop if number equals null. I have getting the message like this "D/jdwp: processIncoming
D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x6, cmdSet=0x1, len=0xB, id=0x2873C, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x0"

Comment: You *will* exit the while loop when `number` is null. No two ways about it. Possibly you are expecting it to magically become null under the wrong circumstances?

Comment: I have getting the message like this "D/jdwp: processIncoming D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x6, cmdSet=0x1, len=0xB, id=0x2873C, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x0"

Answer (score 1):

`readLine()` returns null at stream, and not before, and end of stream on a socket only occurs when the peer has closed the connection. Your expectations appear to be misplaced.

Comment: any other way without closing the connection

Comment: Any other way to do what? Define your requirement.

Comment: exit the while loop without closing the peer connection

Comment: So all you have to do is define the condition under which you want to exit the `while` loop and you've answered your own question. Nobody else can do that for you.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you are failing at understanding the readline function and your implementation of it. You are reading data from your buffer and comparing the data to null, which is obviously not what you are wanting. So here is how I like to read data from a TCP socket.

```
while(statement == true){
    int count = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer);
    if (count == -1){
        // Socket has been closed
    } else {
        // Data has been read.
        // Do comparison here.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: His problem a that he wants to stop reading at some other (unstated) condition than end of stream. This code does not solve it.

Comment: It sounded pretty clear to me.. there is no other way to end the loop if that's the case.